# Как реализован метод update в restful api?

Tags: веб-программирование, rest, backend

Есть некоторый вопрос по оформлению restfull api, толком никаких стандартов не нашел, поэтому и возникают такие вопросы. Допустим я реализую метод update, как понять, какой запрос для этого мне прописывать put или patch, в чем разница? Где передаются данные для обновления в Body или в Query - параметрах?

Comment: *"Где передаются данные для обновления в Body или в Query"* --- в get параметрах передаются данные в get запросе...... вроде очевидно.................  *"какой запрос для этого мне прописывать put или patch"* --- могут зайти сейчас зануды и писать про идемпотентность (не путатть с импотентностью), но я думаю проще не заморачиваться  и делать patch only